# Why can't I find OS X Yosemite in the Mac App store?

Tags: macos

I need to install OS X Yosemite onto my laptop, but can't find it in App Store.

Comment: Rounding up old 'where can I get macOS' questions to - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the OS X Yosemite installer is no longer available on the Mac App Store.

If you have a *paid* Apple Developer account you can download it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

user163914 is correct. I would have commented on that reply but lack of rep.. sigh.  I see Yosemite 10.10.3 build 14D131 (release date April 8, 2015)  available at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/  There are two files (the actual Yosemite update and a combo update file. Both are over a gigabyte in size, be warned)   but you only need one of them.  Note that it is the only Yosemite install version that comes up in the search.  Hope it helps though.

Apple dev accounts are free by the way, all you need to do is sign in with your Apple ID and accept the dev agreement.

Comment: You have to have a paid developer account to download the full OS X installer from the Apple Developers website and there not even visible with a free account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself, and I conclude that you cannot find it in the search. You can only upgrade to El Capitan in the Updates section. You can log in with the Apple ID you used to install Yosemite, and you will find it in the **Purchased**

Comment: No you won't, you'll see El Capitan as the only option. The only place to find Yosemite is in the Purchased tab, if you previously 'bought' it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, I fixed that